# Texmaker Highlight/Note Functionality

Tags: texmaker, highlighting

I was thinking it would be really useful to me if there is a functionality in texmaker like highlighting some text blocks to easy recognize.

Currently I am writing comments like this

```
%%% Check This Later
```

But the comments can easily overlooked.

So my question is: **Is there a functionality to highlight some textblocks in texmaker to easily recognize later on?**

Comment: Relevant (I am guessing it has not been implemented): https://github.com/n370/texmaker/issues/391

Comment: Last action there in 2015 :D

Answer (score 1):

For a comment less easily overlooked, one can use `%TODO` in Texmaker, which will show in red text against a yellow background. Unfortunately, I have not found a way to highlight the whole comment.

[image: Example of %TODO formatting]